# new File(path) or class.getResourses(path)?

Tags: java

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(SpriteSheet.class.getResource(path));
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(path);
```

I've seen in couple of similar questions here before asking this, but I'm still confused a little.

I spent a bit of time reading java docs on those but it made the whole picture even more complex.

What do I need to use for uploading a resource in my program and what is the difference between the two?

Comment: You have typo error here : `ImageIO.read(new File(path);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SpriteSheet.class.getResource(path)` finds the file that is in your java classpath.

`new File(path)` finds the file in anywhere on the file system

if your resource is in your classpath use `class.getResource(path)`

Comment: Afair if you using `new File(path)` it will only work if the file is not inside of the jar file. So if he wants to get resources that may be inside of the application he must use `getResource`